# %2C URL causing iOS app crash

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, url, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I have an iOS application which downloads a JSON feed from this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&home=true&maxResults=50&access_token=%@
```

I am storing the URL in a NSString for later use. I am also adding a NSString to the end of the URL which contains an access token which I am using for OAuth Authentication (hence the %@ at the very end of the URL).

Here is how I am storing the URL:

```
NSString *pre_yt_user_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&home=true&maxResults=50&access_token=%@", token_youtube];
```

As you can see part of the URL has a %2C

This is causing a warning and making my iOS app to crash!!

Here are the warning I get:

```
Format specifies type 'unsigned-short' but the argument has type NSString
```

and:

```
More % conversions than data arguments
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can't I store a URL in a string??

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `stringWithFormat` the `%` character is the start of a data argument unless it's escaped. So you need to escape it because you don't want to use it as a supplied parameter. You need to use `%%2C` (because the first `%` escapes the second `%`).

Comment: Ah right. I was not aware of this. Thank you very much :) I will make sure I tick this answer as soon as Stack Overflow allows me to do so :)